# Split code across multiple SRC blocks?

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming

For my current config, I'm tangling an org-mode buffer into my `init.el`, and I have a few sections where I'd like to insert rich text between segments of Emacs lisp code, like the following:

```
...

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(use-package exwm
  :config
  (exwm-enable)
#+END_SRC

I find that four workspaces is enough to start out with, and I like being able
to use my X windows across workspaces.

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
  :init
  (setq exwm-workspace-number 4
        exwm-workspace-show-all-buffers t
        exwm-layout-show-all-buffers t)
#+END_SRC

...
```

The issue is, if I `C-c '` to edit the second SRC block, it reindents to the beginning of the line. Smartparens is also unhappy about any unmatched closing parentheses I have in subsequent blocks.

Is there anything in org-mode that would support something like this? Perhaps some marker I can tag each block with as a hint that they should all be pulled into the same Org Src buffer when I `C-c '` on one of them?

Comment: I would not split a single expression between multiple src blocks: it's like having `y = x + ` in one block and `x*4` in another: they cannot be evaluated independently and it is very confusing. Why not add comments to the src block? They will appear in `init.el` but so what? You can never have enough documentation.

Comment: Note also that you can use `<<noweb>>` syntax. One `(use-package` block with multiple `<<subsections>>`, and you can define the subsections elsewhere. Would that help?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @mankoff. This is the closest to what I was looking for, but it's unfortunately still a bit too much overhead for my tastes. It seems what I'm trying to do doesn't make much sense in Org, so I've deferred to a plain init.el with comments.

Comment: What about multiple `use-package` statements as I suggest in the answer below? What about that doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here and probably should have 2 questions. First  issue is the indenting;  second is the bracket matching for smartparens.

You can indent the whole tangled source file after saving it. This idea is taken from [Grant Rettke's page](https://github.com/grettke/help).

The relevant code is

```el
(defun help/org-babel-post-tangle-hook-fn ()
  (interactive)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
  (save-buffer))
(add-hook 'org-babel-post-tangle-hook #'help/org-babel-post-tangle-hook-fn)
```

To deal with the bracket issue, I would look at [weaving and literate programming](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#literate-programming) and Grant Rettke's link above, so that each code block is balanced, e.g.:

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(use-package exwm
  :config
  (exwm-enable)
:init
<<exwm>>
) ; close use-package
#+END_SRC
```

and

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle no :noweb-ref exwm
  (setq exwm-workspace-number 4
        exwm-workspace-show-all-buffers t
        exwm-layout-show-all-buffers t) ; parens balanced in code block
#+END_SRC
```

By placing the `:init` in the top level block, the code in the other block is valid elisp and so, when editing the block in a buffer, you can execute it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(use-package exwm ... )` multiple times. That might help.

Comment: Maybe but doesn't that defeat the purpose of `use-package`? I thought it was to keep the configuration of the package all in one place (but I don't use it, so this may be a wee bit off...)

Comment: I think `use-package` is more general than that. There are other purposes, like tighter syntax. And there may be logical reasons to not keep things in one place, and this supports that elegantly.